# Can't pass complex parameters from jquery post to WebAPI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-cordova

I have a ASP MVC project with WebAPI functions . I am trying to call those APIs through jquery POST request in my 'Tools for apache cordove' project . (visual studio 2015)
it works for most functions . but I have one function with complex parameters :

```
public JsonResult LoadHomePage(MostGoodsViewer mostgoodsviewer, SimilarItems newsitems, SimilarItems reviewitems, SimilarItems imaginalitems, string subDomain)
```

All parameters are complex (except the last one) . for example :

```
public class MostGoodsViewer
{
    public MostGoodsViewer()
    {
        ListGoodTypeId = new List<string>();
        listPropertySetID = new List<int?>();
    }
    public List<string> ListGoodTypeId { get; set; }
    public List<int?> listPropertySetID { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to call this API . first of all , I declare my parameters :

```
var mostgoodsviewerP =
    {
        ListGoodTypeId: [],
        listPropertySetID: [],
        PageSize: 13
    };
var newsitemsP =
    {
        ItemCodeText: "/",
        ItemTypeId: 15,
        Count: 9
    };
var reviewitemsP =
  {
      ItemCodeText: "/",
      ItemTypeId: 19,
      Count: 9
  };
var imaginalitemsP =
  {
      ItemCodeText: "/",
      ItemTypeId: 20,
      Count: 9
  };
```

Next, I use POST method :

```
xhr = $.post('https://localhost:44302/Home/LoadHomePage', {
        mostgoodsviewer: JSON.stringify(mostgoodsviewerP),
        newsitems: JSON.stringify(newsitemsP),
        reviewitems: JSON.stringify(reviewitemsP),
        imaginalitems: JSON.stringify(imaginalitemsP),
        subDomain: 'electronic'

    },
    function (data) {
      //  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            var a = data._goodsorderByTotalVisit;
            // other stuff
        }
    }).fail(function (data) {
        alert("error");
    });
```

I also tried using jQuery.param instead of JSON.stringify but no difference .
it always jumps into fail method with data "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Then I tried using Fiddler program to send request instead of my cordova project and running my MVC project with a breakpoint under function's header.
What I realized is parameters are not correct . for example, integers are all zero . I don't know what to do now !

Comment: try by apply `[serialize]` attribute on every `model` `class`.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi : I used [Serializable] but still no difference

Comment: i had similar problem and i pass parameter `string` and in jquery use `JSON.stringify()` then i used somthing like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MostGoodsViewer>(mostgoodsviewerString)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like

**Jquery**:

```
xhr = $.post('https://localhost:44302/Home/LoadHomePage', {
        mostgoodsviewer: JSON.stringify(mostgoodsviewerP),
        newsitems: JSON.stringify(newsitemsP),
        reviewitems: JSON.stringify(reviewitemsP),
        imaginalitems: JSON.stringify(imaginalitemsP),
        subDomain: 'electronic'

    },
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult LoadHomePage(string mostgoodsviewer, string newsitems, string reviewitems, string imaginalitems, string subDomain){

   MostGoodsViewer mostGoodsViewer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MostGoodsViewer>(mostgoodsviewer);
    // and for others same thing to follow
}
```

may this will help you to solve this issue.

You can also do

```
$.post(url, data, function(), "json")
```

Here add `"json"` as second `arg` and may your model bind issue fixed with your current code.

Comment: Try this. If it will helpful to you do upvote and make it answer.

Comment: Thanks, I had also another problem with ssl , but this is a good solution to the issue I mentioned.

Comment: i checked for model binding issue of complex model we need to pass `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` in your code for `$.post` add argument `"json"`

Comment: @armanradan i think second solution is the actual solution i found. and may it works as our expectation. It can not get it a json structure. so we need to provide `contenttype` so in Controller it will bind with Model